# Series Solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I'm trying to complete a practice exam for a class, but I'm having problems verifying my answers. I looked online, but I couldn't find any applet that calculate power series solutions to equations easily, so I thought this would be the best place to ask.

The equation is (4-t<sup>2</sup>)y''+2y=0

The recurrence relation I calculated is a<sub>n+2</sub>=<sup>(a<sub>n</sub>(n<sup>2</sup>-n-1))</sup> ⁄ <sub>((n+2)(n+1))</sub>

I calculated y=a<sub>0</sub>(1-(<sup>x<sup>2</sup></sup> ⁄ <sub>2</sub>)-(<sup>x<sup>4</sup></sup> ⁄ <sub>24</sub>)+...)+a<sub>1</sub>(x-(<sup>x<sup>3</sup></sup> ⁄ <sub>6</sub>)-(<sup>x<sup>5</sup></sup> ⁄ <sub>24</sub>)+...)

Sorry for any formatting issues; that's the first time I've used html in awhile. Does that solution look right at all? Thanks in advance for any help.

---

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps check your calculation again. 
\begin{align*}
4a_{2}+a_{0} & =0\\
12a_{3}+a_{1} & =0
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a_{n+2} & =\frac{n-2}{4\left(n+2\right)}a_{n},\quad n=2,3,\cdots
\end{align*}

Comment: Hey, I'm really sorry. I forgot to turn on notifications for this post, so I didn't think there was anything here. I'll check my work and see if I can get those solutions. Thanks so much for the taking the time to comment. Sorry again it took so long to respond.

Comment: I see what happened. I lost a two and four when I went to calculate the recursion relation. Thanks again! Also, how did you get such perfect formatting?

Comment: You are very welcome. For typesetting, I usually put it in some LaTeX editor, then copy & paste. Hope this helps.